# I want to skip a specific form of WP Forms, if that is already submitted by a user

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I have an opt-in form which I wanted to show when a visitor came to that page until visitor submits the form. Once visitor submitted that opt-in form a specific page then that page should not appear, instead redirect to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by using process complete hook of wp forms.

```
    function wpform_set_submitted_cookie( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

    // Set the third parameter to specify a cookie expiration time,
    // otherwise it will last until the end of the current session.
    setcookie( 'wpform_form_submitted', 'true' );
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete_{form-ID}', 
'wpform_set_submitted_cookie',10,4);


function wpform_protect_confirmation_page() {
    if(is_page('{your-page-slug}')&&isset( $_COOKIE['wpform_form_submitted'])) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpform_protect_confirmation_page' );
```